# AsynTask Never Runs in IntentService

Tags: java, android, intentservice

I am trying to use following code:

```
public class SeparateProcessService extends IntentService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener
{
public SeparateProcessService() {
        super("IntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        new UploadData().execute();


    }

}
```

When the line of asynctask is executed it is either skipped by compiler or ignored.

any one guide me what could be the issue? i am actually trying to upload data to api through intentservice.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are you using an async task in an intent service in the first place? Async task's can only get started on the main thread

Comment: Yes as intent service will run on background in separate thread , my suggestion is its not required to run the async task in intent service. instead you can right ur code in onHandleIntent directly

Comment: thanks guys for your suggestions, let me give a try and update you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AsyncTask.execute()` runs asynchronously.  If you want to block `onHandleIntent()` until the AsyncTask completes, you can use `new UploadData().get()`.  Hopefully you're not doing anything in `onPreExecute` or `onPostExecute`, because those won't get called.

I'd recommend avoiding `AsyncTask` in general and follow the user137021's advice and put the `AsyncTask.doInBackground` code directly in the `IntentService`.